# Genymotion error in AS

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, genymotion

Genymotion doesn't work with Android Studio. It worked at first time, but then I downloaded genymotion plugin for AS and after starting emulator I get an error "The virtual device got no ip..."

Comment: First start your virtual box. Then in Setting go to General there you have to change the type of your OS to your current OS save it and in runs perfectly

Comment: I have already tried this. Doesn't work